# TexStudio: Enable spellchecking in user-defined commands

Tags: macros, texstudio, spelling

I am trying to find a way to enable spell-check in cases such as:

```
\remark[I don't understend this]{$2+5=7$}
```

I found something that might look as an answer but it sadly does not work ... In 'configure TexStudio' -> 'editor' I unchecked both 'hide spelling errors in non-text ..' and 'hide grammar in ...'.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. (I think you suggest that my message is a little crude ? But  I don't want to somehow pollute the question with politeness).

Comment: @ChristianG. No, Andrew suggests that you are asking the first time here and welcomes you to our community. You are on the right way with your 'lag of politeness' (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3602). No worries. Back to topic: I am having the same issue here. Please check for existing issues or write a new one here:  http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/

Comment: Even with both of these options switched off, TeXStudio won't see an error in `\understend[understend]{understend}`. So you could ask more in general than just for optional parameters.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Wow, you are right, I just tested it and it seems like the problem acutally comes from the fact that this is a personalized command... strange. I don't know if I can edit my message but I'll try. Thank you for your comment. Or maybe someone already asked this different question :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the *problem* correctly, when you add a user-defined command, like in my case `\remark`, TexStudio somehow add this new command to a *known-commands list*. (Thereby it is able to manage auto-completion on user-defined commands.) But when it does so, it cannot guess the type of parameters that your command is supposed to take. I don't know what happens precisely here, but for sure the default comportment is not to consider that your new command takes text as parameter.

Therefore, if you want, as I did, to add a new command that will have some text as parameter you have to create a `.cwl` file in order to explicitely specify the type of your command's parameter. In my case I added a file `mycommands.cwl` to `~/.configure/texstudio/`. In this file for now I only have a single line:

```
\remark[text]{text}
```

After doing this, once you restart TexStudio, you can go to `Options -> Configure TexStudio -> Completion` and check `mycommands.cwl`. Now you command is recognized as having text for both parameters and TexStudio will thus spellcheck its content.

---

For more information on .cwl file format you can refer to [TexStudio's manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION).

Comment: That is a nice answer to your own question.