# Texstudio - Spellchecking not working within [ ] brakets with \autocite

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, spelling

In a somewhat similar problem as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238946/texstudio-enable-spellchecking-in-user-defined-commands) in Texstudio spellchecking does not work when I use `\autocite`.

Here is a MWE to show what I mean

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, bookpages=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
address = {Anytown},
booktitle = {Example book},
pages = {5},
title = {{Any book you want}},
year = {2000}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname} % if you’re using biblatex
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\autocite[Transcript of Letter from Mr A to Ms B with some mispelledd texte, p.89]{book1}

\end{document}
```

For some reason the misspelled text in the `\autocite[mispelledd texte]{citekey}` does not show up in the spellchecker. I have the biblatex-chicago.cwl ticked in the completion tab of configure TexStudio as per [the answer in the linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238976/54029) but it has had no effect. I have english-gb dictionary loaded in Texstudio.

My question is that is there any way to enable spellcheck for `\autocite`?

Comment: Where did you get  `biblatex-chicago.cwl ` from and does it specify the optional arguments as `text`?

Comment: The `biblatex-chicago.cwl` on my system is empty. So I guess you will have to fill it with the appropriate stuff, when I added `\autocite[text]{text}` to my version of the file I did get spell-checking on `mispelledd texte`.

Comment: @moewe I just ticked the `biblatex-chicago.cwl`on the completion page of the options as per the [maunal](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION040) I didn't do anything after that. As per your comment you seem to have a solution so if you wish to add what you did as an answer that would be great. If it makes any difference to your answer I use ubuntu.

Comment: Just find `biblatex-chicago.cwl` on your system and follow the suggestions in the question you linked to. I didn't do anything else.

Comment: @moewe Ok, Should I mark my question as a duplicate to easier link to the answer?

Comment: That is probably a good idea.